# Improving Mysql query with multiple BIT(1) fields

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm running some queries which update some tables using several BIT(1) fields in the WHERE clause besides other criteria from INT fields which are mostly a list of values. However, in the EXPLAIN command I see the engine uses the INT fields first rather than the BIT(1) fields in order to scan the tables.

While it's understandable not to rely on BIT(1) fields since that would only shorten the scan by half in the average case, I know that only a minority of the rows would actually fullfill the BIT(1) results (as in "pending" vs "closed" where almost all rows are "closed") so that would be more efficient.

Is there a way to write a query in order to make the MySQL engine to use the BIT(1) criteria first?
Since several BIT(1) are used in the query, would an index on all those fields work?

Comment: bit can hold up to 64 bit, so that there is no need to have multiple bit cpöumns, but for optimization there is more information needed see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions

Answer (score 0):

For a single Boolean column:

```
BIT(1) -- 1 byte
TINYINT -- 1 byte (-128..127 or 0..255)
ENUM('unknown', 'pending', 'closed') -- 1 byte, up to 255 distinct values
```

For several Boolean columns combined:

```
TINYINT UNSIGNED -- 8 bits in 1 byte
INT UNSIGNED -- 32 bits in 4 bytes
(etc)
SET -- up to 64 bits in up to 8 bytes
```

You can manipulate or test multiple bits simultaneously in all these cases.

Describe your application further, including the data and the queries.  Maybe we can advise further.